# How do you block emails from unknown domains?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention, blacklist

I am constantly getting emails from `@xyz.dfg.cloud`, `@fou.vm.blah`, and so on.

I was thinking of whitelisting domains like `hotmail`, `outlook`, `gmail` and block everything else.

I would like to apply a filter that would mimic the `!` (not)  operator so I could specify `!@hotmail.com`, `!@gmail.com`, `!outlook.com`, and so on.

How can I filter Gmail messages in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The `not` operator in Gmail searches and filters is the negation symbol `-`

So your search would be:

```
-from:({hotmail.com gmail.com outlook.com})
```

In Gmail search, the parentheses `()` group terms and the braces `{}` imply an `OR` between terms.

The `@` is ignored by Gmail search so can omit it.